# Runtime Error because of ListView id

Tags: java, android

i'm still new at learning java and this is my first android app and it used to work but now it just shows me an error whenever i try to run this page :

```
  package com.ds.rssreader;

    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class StartingPoint extends ListActivity {
    Button Add;
    Button Delete;
    public static String Menu[];
    public static int Menu_counter = 0;
    ListView Sites;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.starting);
        Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
        Delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Delete);
        Sites = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent OpenAddPage = new Intent("com.ds.rssreader.AddPage");
                startActivity(OpenAddPage);
            }
        });
        Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent OpenDeletePage = new Intent(
                        "com.ds.rssreader.DeletePage");
                startActivity(OpenDeletePage);
            }

        });
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

and here it's Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="25dp"
    tools:context="com.ds.rssreader.StartingPoint" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Add"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Add"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Delete"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Delete"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Add"
        android:clickable="true"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ds.rssreader"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ds.rssreader.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ds.rssreader.StartingPoint"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ds.rssreader.StartingPoint" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ds.rssreader.AddPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ds.rssreader.AddPage" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ds.rssreader.DeletePage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ds.rssreader.DeletePage" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ds.rssreader.RSSFeed"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ds.rssreader.RSSFeed" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ds.rssreader.RSSHandler"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ds.rssreader.RSSHandler" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ds.rssreader.RSSItem"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ds.rssreader.RSSItem" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

the error causes the program to crash whenever i try to open this page and it says :
E/AndroidRuntime(1085): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ds.rssreader/com.ds.rssreader.StartingPoint}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

and when i try to debug it, it tells me that there is something's source not found
and for the record when i make any other page opens instead of this page it opens without any problems.
REMEMBER GUYS : I'm new in java so don't say big words try to simplify as much as you can

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your layout, change:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

to

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```

and, in your class change:

```
Sites = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to

```
Sites = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```